# Como reducir las imágenes recibidas en el cuerpo de un mensaje de Gmail usando un bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, gmail

## Pregunta

¿Cómo reducir las imágenes recibidas en el cuerpo de un mensaje de Gmail usando un [bookmarklet](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)?

## Contexto

La interfaz web de Gmail no reduce automáticamente las imágenes embebidas en el cuerpo del mensaje cuando su tamaño supera el ancho del marco (`frame`) de lectura del mensaje. Esto dificulta la lectura, pues el texto se extiende a lo ancho de la imagen y provoca que haya que usar la barra de desplazamiento (`scrollbar`) horizontal para leer cada línea.

En algunos casos abrir el mensaje en una nueva ventana soluciona el problema, en otros no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El siguiente [bookmarklet](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) reduce el tamaño de las imágenes en el cuerpo del mensaje de un correo electrónico en la interfaz web de Gmail:

```
javascript:(function(){ function zoomImage(image, amt) { if(image.initialHeight == null) { /* Evitar acumular el error de redondeo */ image.initialHeight=image.height; image.initialWidth=image.width; image.scalingFactor=1; } image.scalingFactor*=amt; image.width=image.scalingFactor*image.initialWidth; image.height=image.scalingFactor*image.initialHeight; } var i,L=document.images.length; for (i=0;i<L;++i) zoomImage(document.images[i], 2); if (!L) alert("Esta página no contiene imágenes."); })();
```

## Referencias

- https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/pagedata.html#zoom_images_out por [Jesse Ruderman](http://www.squarefree.com/)
- [Utilizar bookmarklets para realizar rápidamente tareas comunes de la páginas web](http://mzl.la/1xKsRw2) de la Ayuda de Mozilla.

Comment: El intento me parece bien, pero debieras explicar en dónde se puede/debe colocar ese código para lograr el efecto deseado.

Comment: @jachguate. Gracias por el feedback. En esta pregunta se asume que se sabe que es un bookmarlet. Me parece que en lugar de agregar a esta la explicacion sería mejor crear una nueva ¿qué es un bookmarlet? Por otro lado, el planteamiento sería distinto en un sitio como Web Appliications.

Comment: Llevas parte de razón, sin embargo me pongo en los zapatos de un típico usuario (no programador o informático) que llegó aquí desde google buscando información para resolver ese problema. Con lo que se puede leer en la pregunta o respuesta probablemente se quede perdido.

Comment: @jachguate : Si un usuario llega googleando a esta pregunta también puede googlear acerca de que es un bookmarklet :P . Ya en serio, para facilitarles un poco las cosas por lo pronto agregué tanto a la pregunta como a la respuestas enlaces al artículo de wikipedia sobre bookmarklets.

Comment: jajaja, @Rubén, ¡pensé que podrías responder eso! Excelente, ya con eso creo que queda zanjado el tema. +1